# Resetting [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus]

Tags: ios, phphotolibrary

In testing my app, I'd like to be able to reset the `+[PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus]` to check that the app behaves correctly when the library is not authorized.

I've tried deleting and reinstalling the app, however, the authorization status remains `PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized`.  This is great for users in the real world, but during development I'd like a way to reset it.

Disabling the app in the Settings app disables it, but does not allow me to present the authorization dialog to the user.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've gotten this to work is by nuking the simulator with `Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings`.

Comment: And what about device? Is there any way?